# How do I set overcommit_memory on Google Cloud notebook?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, memory-management, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am using a GCP Vertex managed notebook and I get a memory error which I think can be fixed by:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

but when I run this from a Jupyterlab terminal I am asked for a sudo password, which I do not know. What can I do?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute this command `whoami` to validate the user you are using in Jupyter. Maybe you are authenticating as a Jupyter user, rather than an IAM user.

In case you are logged in as a Jupyter account. You can follow this [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/notebooks/docs/ssh-access). This will allow you to log in with your user with the privileges of your account.

Another option would be to use this command [`sudo -i`](https://www.maketecheasier.com/differences-between-su-sudo-su-sudo-s-sudo-i/#:%7E:text=which%20increases%20security.-,sudo%20%2Di,-Using%20sudo%20%20-i) which runs a shell with root privileges and also acquires the root user's environment.